# Web inspector not working correctly in sublime text 2

Tags: google-chrome, sublimetext2

When I try to run web inspect in sublime text 2 it produces this error:

```
[619:1799:0524/104420:ERROR:process_singleton_mac.cc(103)] Unable to obtain profile lock.
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 20]
```

The following it my configuration file:

```
{
    "chrome_path": {
        "osx": "/Applications/Google Chrome Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Canary",
        "windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\chrome.exe",
        "linux": "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
    },
    "chrome_profile": "Default",
    "chrome_remote_port": "9222",
    "breakpoint_scope": "swi.breakpoint",
    "current_line_scope": "swi.current",
    "interactive_scope": "mcol_0088CCFF.settings",
    "stack_layout": {
        "cols": [0.0, 0.6, 1.0],
        "rows": [0.0, 0.7, 1.0],
        "cells": [[0, 0, 2, 1], [0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2]]
    },
    "console_layout": {
        "cols": [0.0, 0.6, 1.0],
        "rows": [0.0, 0.7, 1.0],
        "cells": [[0, 0, 2, 1], [0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2]]
    },
    "reload_on_start": true,
    "reload_on_save": true,
    "set_script_source": false,
    "open_stack_current_in_new_tab": false,
    "pause_on_exceptions": "uncaught",
    "breaks": {}
}
```

Know what is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Got this same error, that happens when Chrome is already running. Try closing Chrome and then hit the command in Sublime Text "Start Google Chrome with remote debug port 9222" [image: command in Sublime Text to start Chrome with Web Inspector]